# Not able to setup org-agenda-files

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, microsoft-windows

I am Emacs and org-mode noob and using MS Windows 10. I would like to add a folder containing all org files to my `org-agenda-files` in my `.emacs`.

1. Location of my `.emacs` file:
   `c:/Users/Guest User/AppData/Roaming/`
2. Location of dropbox folder contaning all `.org` files:
   `C:\Users\Guest User\Dropbox\workEMACS`
3. Location of Dropbox application:
   `c:/Users/Guest User/AppData/Roaming/Dropbox`

Specifically, I don't know what to add in the directory path
`(setq org-agenda-files '("~/WhatToAddHere"))`

P.S. [ELI5](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ELI5)

Comment: Well, you state that you are storing your files in the Dropbox folder and then you state that your `org-agenda-files` variable does *not* contain the path to the Dropbox folder ... :)  Have you *tried* adding your Dropbox path to your `org-agenda-files` list?  Have you typed `M-x describe-variable RET org-agenda-files RET`?  Have you Googled and looked at various settings for the `org-agenda-files` *variable*?  I would bet my lunch money that the first Google search for **org-agenda-files dropbox windows** would yield some examples ....  Did you encounter any errors with something you *tried*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found that following works perfectly:

```
(custom-set-variables
'(org-directory "C:/Users/Guest User/Dropbox/workEMACS")
'(org-agenda-files (list org-directory)))
```

Courtesy: [How to add .org files under org-directory to agenda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37056872/3282330)